# read text file with delimiter nsstring

Tags: iphone

I have a text file like this

question1
question2
question3

I want to read only the first line into a nsstring

after that I want to mark the first line so the next time, skip the first line, but I don't know how to do it, I have this code for read but give me only the third line

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"qa" ofType:@"txt"];  

NSString *myText = [NSString  stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];   
NSArray *lines = [myText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];    
for(myText in lines)
{

    texview.text = myText;  

}


}
```

Ok I try this code, Do not work, what I am Doing wrong?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString * const kKey = @"OneTimeKey";
NSObject  *keyValue = [defaults  objectForKey:kKey];



NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"qa" ofType:@"txt"];  

NSString *myText = [NSString  stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];   
NSArray *lines = [myText componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];    



if (keyValue==nil) {
    for(myText in lines)

    {

        preguntadia.text = myText;  

        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:kKey];

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your "for" is executed really fast, so fast that you can only see when the last element of the array is set to your text view.

What you can do is have a variable which specifies which one of the strings to show next and, with a timer, set a different string on your text view every number of seconds, so you can actually see the changes.

Bonus, you can make it cycle with something like this:

```
-(void)updateText{
    [textView setText:[lines objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
    currentIndex++;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % [lines count];
}
```

So when it reaches the last string, it shows the first again.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store a line counter locally to keep track, I think. That is easily accomplished with something like this to save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setInteger:lineCount forKey:@"lineCountKey"];
```

and fetch:

```
int lineCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] integerForKey:@"lineCountKey"];
```

and then just read and discard `lineCount` lines when you open the file.

Now, splitting the line you want into multiple pieces, you can use the NSString method `componentsSeparatedByString:`, but be careful. If your "questions" are actually multi-word questions, you'll need to pick a separator other than space. Vertical bar (|) might be a good choice, then you can do something like this:

```
NSArray *questions = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

NB: Code typed from memory; not compiled. :-)

Comment: something like this: 
 
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"qa" ofType:@"txt"];  
 
 NSString *myText = [NSString  stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];   
 NSArray *lines = [myText componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];    
 
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString * const kKey = @"OneTimeKey";
 NSObject  *keyValue = [defaults  objectForKey:kKey];
 
 
 
 for(myText in lines)
 
 {
  if ( keyValue==nil)
  {
  preguntadia.text = myText;  
  
  [defaults setBool:YES forKey:kKey];
  }
  
  }
 
 
}

Comment: That's a little hard to read, but I don't think that's going to do what you want, unless I am totally misunderstanding. How about: try the code and see what happens? :-)

Comment: I have to say: At this point, I am really unclear what you are trying to accomplish! :-) If you want to keep track of which line you should display from a multi-line file, store a value in user defaults to remember the line number of the last line read. In your code, read and discard that many lines, then display the "next" line and update your stored line number value +1. You shouldn't set the updated user default value inside your loop; that's inefficient.